# Fatal error encountered during command execution - C# Only in Linux

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a `.net` core `web -api application` that run in production on `Linux` server.
I get exception when i try to run this query on production environment -

> 'Fatal error encountered during command execution.'

When I am trying to debug it locally on Windows server i didn't get this exception at all.

**Query:**

```
UPDATE `OfferUrlData` SET NextPageUrl=REPLACE(NextPageUrl,@OldUrl,@newUrl) WHERE NextPageUrl LIKE @oldUrlSearch
```

This is my params during execution time:
@oldUrl = gooogle.com, @oldUrlSearch = https://gooogle.com%, @newUrl = google.com'

Any idea why I get this exception only on production (`Linux`) and not locally
(`Windows`)? **both work with the same rds.**

Comment: Possibly something around backslashes usage (Windows) vs slashes usage (Linux) in the writing of urls.

Comment: thanks, this my params on execution time: oldUrl = gooogle.com, oldUrlSearch = https://gooogle.com%, newUrl = google.com'.
do you think the issue is oldUrlSearch ?

Comment: Please provide the exception details, including all inner exceptions: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: What MySQL library are you using, and which version? Mono or .NET Core? Which version?

Comment: Fatal error encountered during command execution. StackTrace - at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Comment: I use MySql.Data version - 8.0.17  Library from NuGet package manager.